# IntellIJ IDEA Kotlin - Expecting an element

Tags: kotlin, generics, intellij-idea, mockito

I am new to Kotlin and am now struggling with unit testing my code.

I am trying to mock the `restTemplate` that uses an array in the `exchange` method. I found that the correct way to do that would be

```kotlin
ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<Array<DataDto>>>any()
```

however compiler throws an error saying `Expecting an element` and doesn't allow me to qualify the type for `any()`. Is there any setting for IDEA to fix this compiler error?

I use Java 17 as the SDK, but I tried it Kotlin SDK 1.6.10 as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type arguments go after the function name (and before the `()`), not before so you need to use

```
ArgumentMatchers.any<ParameterizedTypeReference<Array<DataDto>>>()
```